# How to run and compile c with command prompt windows 8

Tags: c, windows-8, command-prompt

I am learning how to code in my college classes and work mainly with my hp envy running windows 8. I have not been able to find a program or extension that allows me to run and compile c code on my computer through the command prompt. Does anybody have suggestions? I have looked on my own and have had to remove several viruses from my computer because of this. I also have a mac if there is an option for that. Would it be best if I just shelled out for a linux based laptop? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: try to use an IDE like codeblocks

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge Doesn't Codeblocks require you to have a third-party compiler installed?

Comment: Yes. But, Check [here](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26#windows).
*codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe file includes the GCC compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 4.7.1, 32 bit).*

Comment: You could write a 'make' file and run it from the command line.  The makefile would contain all the items you need to perform for your specific project.

Answer (score 0):

You can install visual studio express and use it for development

It is free

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx